# Multiply UARTS STM32

Tags: stm32, uart, stm32cubeide

I have two USART lines, the first device sends a command, the second responds. I want it all to go through STM32. I'm tracking two UARTs via interrupts. I need the program to receive commands from the first device, send them to the second and return a response from it to the first device. But I ran into a problem, for some reason many messages do not reach, sometimes only commands are read in a row, and then a couple of responses are returned, although it is necessary that there be a command-response.

I am requesting to receive bytes in an infinite loop
`while (1) { HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) masterData, 1); HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, (uint8_t*) peripheralData, 1); }`

Comment: And when I receive the data, I send it to another device
`void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if(huart == &huart2)
    {
         printf("MASTER value1=%X,value2=%X\r\n", masterData[0], masterData[1]);
         HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3, (uint8_t *)masterData, sizeof(*masterData));
    } else if (huart == &huart3) {
         printf("PERIPHERAL value1=%X,value2=%X\r\n", peripheralData[0], peripheralData[1]);
         HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)peripheralData, sizeof(*peripheralData));
    }
}`

Comment: You can edit your question at any time to add more details. Please don't add extra details in comments. Also, you can use proper code blocks in your question (bounded by lines containing three backtick characters), rather than single backticks that you use in comments.

Comment: Always check the return values from HAL functions. You'll find that the calls in your infinite loop are all failing (except maybe the first two).

Answer (score 1):

Mutiple issues here.

1. `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` is a callback function, which is called from UART's interrupt. Your code stalls, i.e. next reception is not started, untill everything is printed, . Never use `printf` within an interrupt, since it is usualy a blocking call.
2. You are receiving and transmitting from the same buffers - for `uart2` it is `masterData`. Even if printfs are removed from the callback, `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` will start transfer from `masterData` buffer, and main loop will start reception into the same buffer. You need to implement a message queue, or at least double-buffering.
3. `sizeof(*masterData)` is not number of bytes received, it is a size of array element, which is probably 1. Actual size should be stored somewhere within huart2 handle.
4. You setting up reception for 1 byte, and printf-ing two bytes.

Perhaps there more, but that's what I see at a glance.